# Scheduled event from django to react-native

Tags: python, django, react-native, events, microservices

I built a web service with Django and PostgreSQL.
I have two apps that use Django backend- react and react-native.
I want to send scheduled events with data from Django to React Native, The times for sending an event are stored in a table in the database (because they are dynamic - there are default times).

Does anyone have any idea know how I can implement this?

thanks

expected:
react-native app will listen to events.
Django service will send to react-native app scheduled data.

Comment: probably [webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)